# Como pegar o resultado da Requisição no Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, web-service, rest, post, retrofit

Bom, estou começando a estudar Android, já até fiz requisição com Volley mas um amigo me indicou Retrofit por ser bem mais rápido e "simples". Porém ainda não consegui entender muito.

Tenho um WebService aonde eu pretendo fazer login. Tenho que enviar informações que pego pelo facebook, como Email, Nome, Access_token.. Depois minha aplicação Ruby valida o login e me devolve uma Api_key para requisições futuras. Até então consegui fazer a requisição, porem não consigo pegar o API_KEY que meu WebService retorna em formato JSON.

Minha interface:

```
public interface APIService {

 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("login")
 Call<JSONObject> createUser(@Field("name") String name,
                             @Field("email") String email,
                             @Field("access_token") String access_token,
                             @Field("provider") String provider);

}
```

Classe Geradora de Serviço:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://rocky-cliffs-4726.herokuapp.com/api/v1/";

 private static OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

 private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
         new Retrofit.Builder()
                 .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

 public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
     Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();
     return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
 }
}
```

Na minha activity tenho o metodo:

```
public void logar(String name, String email, String acess_token, String provider) {

    APIService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class);

    Call<JSONObject> call = service.createUser(name, email, acess_token, provider);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<JSONObject> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            try {
                String api_key = response.body().getString("api_key");
                Log.i("TAG",api_key);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

O JSON que minha aplicação retorna:

```
{"success" : true, "json" : {"data": {"api_key":"API_KEY_AQUI"}}}
```

Comment: Você está conseguindo retornar o JSON corretamente?

Answer (score 1):

retorne o seguinte json

```
{"api_key":"API_KEY_AQUI"}
```

Crie uma classe model que represente o mesmo

```
public class suaclasse{
 private String api_key;
//get and set
}
```

Atualize sua interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("login")
 Call<SuaClasse> createUser(@Field("name") String name,
                             @Field("email") String email,
                             @Field("access_token") String access_token,
                             @Field("provider") String provider);
```

Dentro do onResponse faça:

```
response.body().getApiKey();//metodo get definido em SuaClasse
```